# При отправке почты в письмо через каждые 991 символ вставляется перенос строки

Tags: postfix, email, php

Отправка из PHP нативным mail(), на сервере стоит postfix-2.6.6-2.1.el6_0До передачи в mail() тело письма не имеет переносов строк, на почту приходит письмо, в котором после каждых 991 символов вставлен перенос строки. Само-собой, очень мешает. Не знаю, куда смотреть и на что грешить.

P.S. Письма идут в кодировке windows-1251

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из конфига постфикса

```
# By default, the line length is limited to 990 characters, because# some server implementations cannot receive mail with long lines.# #smtp_line_length_limit = 990
```